# How to resolve error in SoapUI while reading the Excel file

Tags: groovy, apache-poi, soapui

I am getting below error while reading an xls file

`org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.notimplementedexception (Countif formula)`

Can you please help how to resolve the issue?

I have tried all poi latest jar files.

Below are the Poi jars that I have used

- poi-3.15.jar
- SoapUi version 5.5
- jdk - 1.8.0_151
- jre - 1.8.0_211

Comment: When reading? Or when evaluating formulas? Without any code, we can't see what you're doing wrong...

Comment: Hi Garravarr - The excel file contains some formula and it was working fine in my other laptop however its not working in my office laptop. So it seems the issue is not in the code but somewhere in the jar file or Java. I have updated my jar file details now in the original post

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Apache POI? What happens when you upgrade to the latest stable one?

Comment: I have used 4.0 however facing the same issue

Comment: Can anyone please update me on this?

Comment: You've still not included any code, so we can't really spot much what's wrong...